# What are the corresponding configs in MySQL for deletion behaviors in PostgreSQL for CASCADE, RESTRICT, NO ACTION, SET NULL, SET DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, cascading-deletes

I have experience with Postgres and their deletion behavior for foreign key references (quoting from the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)):

- `NO ACTION` (default): If any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an error is raised
- `RESTRICT`: Prevents deletion of a referenced row. The essential difference between these two choices is that `NO ACTION` allows the check to be deferred until later in the transaction, whereas `RESTRICT` does not.
- `CASCADE`: When a referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well.
- `SET NULL`: Causes the referencing columns to be set to `NULL` when the referenced row is deleted.
- `SET DEFAULT`: Causes the referencing columns to be set to their default values when the referenced row is deleted. Note that these do not excuse you from observing any constraints. For example, if an action specifies `SET DEFAULT` but the default value would not satisfy the foreign key, the operation will fail.

Are there corresponding configs for all of these behaviors in MySQL as well? I was looking through the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) but didn't find anything helpful...

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! If you add this as an answer I'll accept it so you get your points! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the mysql docs here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

```
reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
```